# Android Studio no layout morphing

Tags: android-studio

When creating a blank layout I get RelativeLayout and in the Component Tree there is no morphing option to change the layout. If I manually edit it to another layout then morphing becomes available, however LinearLayout is never an option and when changed to Relative it disappears.

How can I get it to allow me to change to linear or have all the options available without having to edit the xml?

Thanks.

I'm on beta 0.8.6